# watson dialogService return null when I try to update. Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I created a dialog and generated a response with an id. When I try to update the dialog, the API call returns a null answer instead of the dialog ID. Is my code wrong or is this a bug?

```
    ServiceCall dialog = service.updateDialog("ID", new File("file/template.xml"));
    System.out.println(dialog.execute());
```

It appears on the console in eclipse, when I try to update ...
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use CURL?

Comment: Curl command I mean. A way to check if it's your code or the service.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, please try to update/access the dialog that you have created by using an equivalent curl command. I realize that you're actually working in Java, but (as Simon said), trying the same command using curl from the command-line should help you determine if the problem is in the arguments that you;re supplying or in the Dialog service itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `updateDialog()` method returns `void` because the Dialog API returns `{}`.
See https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/dialog-v1#!/Content/putAppFile

It makes sense because when you update a dialog you get the same `id` you use to update the dialog.